# Scheme - Blackjack Program (SICP) / Learning to program

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I have decided to learn to program reading/doing SICP.

I'm using DrRacket and  http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/

I wrote a blackjack program https://github.com/fnava621/scheme_blackjack . It works.

Can you make this program more Readable and succinct?

Did I put too many comments? Not enough comments? How do I make this program "better"?

I'm also throwing down the gauntlet.  Can you make a program that uses "optimal" strategy and  determines what the probability of the player winning against the dealer (using n sample size)? I will do the same and compare code.

Thanks for reading/doing, 
Fernando Nava

Comment: Perhaps you should try to write it in a harder scheme variant. Racket is quite different, easier. I personally don't like the 'if's. I can read and understand the whole program.

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

1. Avoid using so much mutation, ie `set!`.
2. Avoid redefining built-in functions, like `length`.
3. Add signatures and purpose statements to each of your functions.  See [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/htdp2e-part1.html#%28part._design-func%29) for an explanation.
4. Write tests!  Try using `rackunit`, documented [here](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/rackunit/)

Answer (score 2):

Let me focus on a single function `show-deck`.  I see what it's doing, but the recursion can be simplified a bit.  Making it easier to read might be slightly less efficient, but we're talking about 52 cards here... :)

The inner and outer loops are entangled in the original code.  Here's one version that disentangles them:

```
(define (show-deck1 first-list second-list)
  (define (outer-loop first-list second-list)
    (cond
      ((null? first-list)
       '())
      (else
       (append (inner-loop (car first-list) second-list)
               (outer-loop (cdr first-list) second-list)))))

  (define (inner-loop x second-list)
    (cond
      ((null? second-list)
       '())
      (else
       (cons (cons x (car second-list))
             (inner-loop x (cdr second-list))))))

  (outer-loop first-list second-list))
```

We can apply a simplification: with the definition expressed this way, it's easier to see that `map` can be used to do the `inner-loop`.

```
(define (show-deck2 first-list second-list)
  (cond
    ((null? first-list)
     '())
    (else
     (define x (car first-list))
     (append (map (lambda (y) (cons x y)) second-list)
             (show-deck2 (cdr first-list) second-list)))))
```

This makes it easier to see the structure of the outer iteration.  We can take `map` one step further, and use it for both the inner and outer loopings, and use `(apply append ...)` to flatten the substructure introduced by the nested use of `map`:

```
(define (show-deck3 first-list second-list)
  (apply append 
         (map (lambda (x)
                (map (lambda (y) (cons x y)) second-list))
              first-list)))
```

Your version avoids the `(apply append ...)` stuff altogether by cleverly threading the computation, but it's at the expense of some readability.  One way to avoid the `(apply append ...)` and still get the benefit of easily seeing the nested loop structure is to use a `foldr` approach rather than a `map` approach:

```
(define (foldr f acc l)
  (cond
    ((null? l) acc)
    (else 
     (f (car l)
        (foldr f acc (cdr l))))))

(define (show-deck first-list second-list) 
  (foldr (lambda (x acc)
           (foldr (lambda (y acc)
                    (cons (cons x y) acc))
                  acc
                  second-list))
         '()
         first-list))
```

This should match what your original code did before.  It relegates the loopness to `foldr`, though, so that all those `iter` functions disappear into uses of `foldr`.

Personally, if I'm writing in full Racket, I'd just code it with `for` loops.  :)  It'd look something like this:

```
;; If we're allowed to use full Racket:
(define (show-deck first-list second-list)
  (for*/list ([x first-list]
              [y second-list])
    (cons x y)))
```